# NullPointerException when trying to send a message to a Client Socket

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, nullpointerexception

I have a ServerHandler class, which creates a new PrintWriter and stores it into a PrintWriter array, The message gets sent by giving the selectedId integer the ID number of the client that should receive the message. When i call the SendMessage() method inside the ServerHandler class it sends the message without a problem, but when i try to call the SendMessage("some message") method from the class that contains the GUI it gives me a NullPointerException.

The posljiSporocilo() is the actual SendMessage() because some methods are in my language

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;

  public class ServerHandler implements Runnable{
Socket klientSocket;
static int userCounter = 0;
static int selectedId = 0;
BufferedReader reader;
static PrintWriter writer;
static PrintWriter[] writerHolder = new PrintWriter[10];

static outputHelper out = new outputHelper();   


public ServerHandler(Socket klientSocket) throws IOException
{
    userCounter++;
    this.klientSocket = klientSocket;
    writer = new PrintWriter(this.klientSocket.getOutputStream());
    writerHolder[userCounter] = writer;

    InputStreamReader inReader = new      InputStreamReader(this.klientSocket.getInputStream());
    reader = new BufferedReader(inReader);

    out.frameOutput(this.klientSocket.getInetAddress().toString(), "Server sprejel povezavo:"); 

    selectedId = 1;
    posljiSporocilo("AutoSent");
```

When i call the posljiSporocilo() method in the actual class it does send the message to the Client.
        }

```
public ServerHandler(){
    // Do not launch the main Constructor
}

public void run(){

    String inMessage = null;
    try{
        while((inMessage = reader.readLine()) != null){
            System.out.println("Server Sprejel: " + inMessage);
        }
    }catch(IOException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public  void selectId(int id){
    selectedId = id;
    out.frameOutput("ID Changed to: " + selectedId, "ID change");


}

public void posljiSporocilo(String message){
    try
    {
        writerHolder[selectedId].println(message);
        writerHolder[selectedId].flush();

    }catch(Exception ex)
    {
        out.frameOutput("ERROR Trying to send a message", "ERR_MESSAGE:");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}


 }
```

The class that contains the GUI stuff:

```
package homeControl;

 IMPORTS

public class mainWindow extends JFrame {

private JPanel contentPane;
private JTextField messageTextField;
ServerHandler svr = new ServerHandler();
outputHelper o = new outputHelper();

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                mainWindow frame = new mainWindow();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public mainWindow() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);

    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    setJMenuBar(menuBar);

    JMenu mnOptions = new JMenu("Options");
    menuBar.add(mnOptions);

    JMenu mnId = new JMenu("ID");
    menuBar.add(mnId);

    JMenuItem idEnaItem = new JMenuItem("ID: 1");
    mnId.add(idEnaItem);
    idEnaItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
            if(event.getActionCommand() != null){
                svr.selectId(1);
                setTitle("ID changed to 1");
            }
        }
    });

    JMenuItem idDvaItem = new JMenuItem("ID: 2");
    mnId.add(idDvaItem);
    idDvaItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
            if(event.getActionCommand() != null){
                svr.selectId(2);
                setTitle("ID changed to 2");
            }
        }
    });

    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    messageTextField = new JTextField();
    messageTextField.setBounds(10, 209, 292, 20);
    contentPane.add(messageTextField);
    messageTextField.setColumns(10);

    JButton sendButton = new JButton("Send");
    sendButton.setBounds(312, 208, 89, 23);
    contentPane.add(sendButton);
    sendButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){

            if(event.getActionCommand() != null)
            {
            svr.posljiSporocilo("THIS MESSAGE DOES NOT GET SENT");
            }
```

When i call the posljiSporocilo() method from this class it gives me a NullPointerException

```
        }
    });
}
 }
```

i hope i gave you enough information, Thanks!

Debugmode SS:
    http://imageshack.us/f/543/1vea.png/

Comment: What specific line in your code gave the NPE?  What objects are being referenced on that line that could be null?

Comment: It seems the most plausible cause is that you try to reference an element in the PrintWriter array that is not there, thus causing a NullPointerException.

Comment: @11684 You were right, when the posljiSporocilo() method gets called and executes the writerHolder[someIndex] cmd all of the places in the array are NULL, however i don't know why they are NULL, because the array is static and i'm not executing/changing the writerHolder array with another thread, but simply with another instance of the class.

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell me why you are incrementing the counter at the beginning? this will cause that the 0th element in your writerHolder array will never get populated.

```
userCounter++;
this.klientSocket = klientSocket;
writer = new PrintWriter(this.klientSocket.getOutputStream());
writerHolder[userCounter] = writer;
```

I am guessing your NPE is related to this. if your selected id is 0, then the code inside method posljiSporocilo will throw NPE.

Comment: To keep track of how many people connected.. so that when i call the selectId(user id) method i can compare it to the number of clients

ex:
if(selectedId > userCounter){PRINT("There are not so many users connected")}

Comment: My question was why at the beginning? Move it to the end of the code snippet I put above and see if you are still getting NPE.

Comment: you always call the default ServerHandler() class from your GUI, Dont you think you will have to call ServerHandler(Socket) constructor?

Comment: Yes, i call the ServerHandler() constructor because i don't want the GUI class to have anything to do with the sockets and java.net related stuff, i just wan't to use the posljiSporocilo() and selectId() method.

Answer (score 0):

> but when i try to call the SendMessage("some message") method from the class that contains the GUI it gives me a NullPointerException.

This is very hard to figure out because you are not showing *which* line is actually throwing the NPE.  In looking at your code I see the following code.  I see where the `writeHolder` array is initialized but I wonder if the `writerHolder[selectedId]` could be `null`:

```
public void posljiSporocilo(String message){
    try {
        writerHolder[selectedId].println(message);
        writerHolder[selectedId].flush();
        ...
```

Could `selectedId` be *larger* than the `userCounter` value?  If multiple threads are calling the initialization, you probably should use an `AtomicInteger` instead of a non-synchronized `static int`.

I'd learn to use a [debugger in eclipse](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseDebugging/article.html) and step through your program looking at each of the objects to see which one is null.

Comment: I made a test, i wanted to the what the values of userCounter and the value of selectedId are at the time that the posljiSporocilo() method gets called, i found out that when the method gets called on its own in the constructor both of those values are 1. But when i call the posljiSporocilo method from the Gui class both of those values are 0, so this is what causes the NPE.. However i still don't know how to fix it.

Comment: If the `selectId` is shared by multiple threads then it should be an `AtomicInteger` as I mention in my post @user2794550.  Any fields that are being updated and shared between threads must be protected and memory synchronized.

Comment: The selectId is(as far as i understand java) being increment by one Thread, however i do not use another thread to change the value i simply use another instance of the serverHandler class which should not be a problem since the selectId integer is static. I found out that when the posljiSporocilo method gets called from the GUI class the writerHolder[] array is NULL on all indexes. I have no idea how to fix it.